# Why does my rounding to two decimals doesn't work with my code?

Tags: python

A school project asks me to do a function that should return the absolute value of the monthly payment rounded to two decimal points.

Can anyone explain me why my code doesn't properly work? Thanks in advance!

```
interest_rate= int(input('Type your interest rate (in %) '))
principal = int(input('Type your principal '))
period = int(input('Type for how many months '))

def calculate_payment(principal, interest_rate, period):
    final_amount = (1 + interest_rate) ** period
    return principal * (interest_rate * final_amount) / 
    (final_amount- 1)

final_amount = str(round(final_amount, 2))

print("your amount that has to be paid after each month is: ", final_amount)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code fails to run: syntax errors, no call of the function, and requires superfluous hand-given input.

Comment: You never call the `calculate_payment()` function. And `final_amount` is a local variable inside the function, you can't use it outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are both missunderstanding the formula for compound interest (aside from stackoverflow) nor is the period for the interest rate detailed (is the interest rate monthly? annually?). If the interest rate is monthly and you will return the interest that will be paid after a month, then the variable period is of no use. Regarding the code, you are not defining the function correctly, nor calling it correctly to make it work. Furthermore if it's compound interest, the value to be paid each month (of interests) will never be equal since unless the interests are being withdraw and not reinvested. Iff that's what you want then check **CASE 2**. Case 1 assumes you are returning the full amount when the operation finishes.

This is what I think you are looking for:

### CASE 1

```
interest_rate= int(input('Type your interest rate (in %) '))
principal = int(input('Type your principal '))
period = int(input('Type for how many months '))

def calculate_payment(principal, interest_rate, period):
    final_amount = principal * ((1+interest_rate/100) ** period)
    return round(final_amount,2)

print("your amount that has to be paid at the end of the period is: ", calculate_payment(principal, interest_rate,period))
```

Output:

```
Type your interest rate (in %) 10
Type your principal 1000
Type for how many months 2
your amount that has to be paid at the end of the period is:  1210.0
```

### CASE 2

```
interest_rate= int(input('Type your monthly interest rate (in %) '))
principal = int(input('Type your principal '))
period = int(input('Type for how many months '))

def calculate_payment(principal, interest_rate, period):
    final_amount = principal * (((1+interest_rate/100)) - 1)
    return round(final_amount,2)

print("your amount that has to be paid after each month is: ", calculate_payment(principal, interest_rate,period))
```

Output:

```
Type your monthly interest rate (in %) 10
Type your principal 1000
Type for how many months 2
your amount that has to be paid after each month is:  100.0
```